# Is the function $\ln(x-\pi)$ square integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have the function

$\ln(r-\pi)$

over the interval $[\pi, r_c]$ where $r_c$ is some positive cut off value of $r$.
Is it square integrable?

If not, would

$(r-\pi)\ln(r-\pi)$

be square integrable?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that $x \ln x$ is bounded near $0$>

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please provide more context and expand your answer, allowing for faster answers and discouraging downvotes and close votes.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $(r-\pi)^{1/4} \ln (r-\pi) \to 0$ as $r\to \pi^+$

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_\pi^{r_c}\log^2(x-\pi)\,dx=\int_{0}^{r_c-\pi}\log^2(x)\,dx$$

Now integrate by parts with $u=\log^2(x)$ and $v=x$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
I&=\left. x\log^2(x)\right|_{0}^{r_c-\pi}-2\int_0^{r_c-\pi}\log(x)\,dx\\\\
&=(r_c-\pi)\log^2(r_c-\pi)-2\int_0^{r_c-\pi}\log(x)\,dx 
\end{align}$$

Can you finish?